# Laravel Sentinel redirect after successful login

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 for a project that we are doing and using sentinel which is a sentry implementation. Link to package is as below

```
https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel
```

When I log in, I need to do a routing which directs to the dashboard page. My code as below in the filters.php under the app folder

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) 
        return Redirect::guest('login');
    else if (!Auth::guest())
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
});
```

But its not working. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel
```

This package uses Sentry2.

referance : [Sentinel Filters](https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel/blob/master/src/filters.php)